# Why is this variable constantly resetting?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a program in VB.net that uses the form load event to prompt for  password.  I have this working, but I am supposed to be showing the attempt number you are at if you fail.   However, my code is always returning "Attempt #1" and never increasing to #2, #3, etc, and I am unsure why it is constantly being reset.

```
Private Function checkPassword(passwordGuess As String)
        Dim isValid As Boolean = False
        Dim password As String = "941206"
        Dim attemptCounter As Integer
        If isValid = False Then
            If password <> txtPassword.Text Then
                attemptCounter += 1
                MessageBox.Show("Login Unsuccesful.",
                            "Attempt #" & attemptCounter)
            Else
                isValid = True
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful.",
                            "Attempt #" & attemptCounter)
                Me.Text = "Attempt #" & attemptCounter
            End If
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub btnConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirm.Click
        Dim password As String
        password = txtPassword.Text
        checkPassword(password)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Every time you call the function, a new 'attemptCounter' is generated. You can ether make it Static ('Static attemptCounter As Integer = 0') or you define it outside the function (I would prefer the first way).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope

Comment: Whether you use a `Static` variable or a member variable, be sure to reset the counter to zero upon success. It's worth nothing that, once compiled, a `Static` variable actually is a member variable. A VB developer may prefer a `Static` variable because it reduces the scope as much as possible but developers who use other languages would probably prefer the member because `Static` variables are a VB peculiarity.

Comment: Thanks Mat and Muffi! I remember reading about the lifetime and scopes of variables and figured it had to do something with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class to store information about attempts that persists across function calls:

```vb
    Public Class attempt
        Public Shared counter As Integer = 0
    End Class
 
    Private Function checkPassword(passwordGuess As String)
        Dim isValid As Boolean = False
        Dim password As String = "941206"
        If isValid = False Then
            If password <> txtPassword.Text Then
                attempt.counter += 1
                MessageBox.Show("Login Unsuccesful.",
                            "Attempt #" & attempt.counter)
            Else
                isValid = True
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful.",
                            "Attempt #" & attempt.counter)
                Me.Text = "Attempt #" & attempt.counter
            End If
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub btnConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirm.Click
        Dim password As String
        password = txtPassword.Text
        checkPassword(password)
    End Sub
```

Comment: I would describe this as "using a sledgehammer to crack a nut". Creating a class to represent one integer value is totally superfluous. Moreover, given that your class is not `Shared`, your code will throw a null reference exception, because you have not initialised your class.

Comment: Fair enough - although given more context, I think it could be useful to the design of the program overall (e.g. it may be relevant to also store when the last login attempt was). You're totally correct about `Shared`, I've updated the answer to reflect this.